# Magento2 default Headers and Footers missing on CMS page

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, cms-pages

When I am adding a CMS Page with layout as 1column xml.
The default header and footer shows fine.

but I have some existing CMS pages which if I update the layout to 1column, it still doesn't show the default header and footers.

If I create a new CMS page and add the same contents, it works, but if delete the existing url key (**of the page for which for which header and footers were not showing**) -  testpage and add the same urlkey testpage to the new page, the headers and footers are removed.

for example I have a CMS page

with url key - `shipping-and-returns`

and I create new page with URL key `shipping` with the same contents it works. but If I delete the page with URL key `shipping-and-returns` and modify the URL key `shipping` to `shipping-and-returns` it doesn't work, means header and footers goes missing.

Need some help, what could be causing this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same thing was happening to me, using claue theme in Magento 2.2

It's not because the `-` in the url, it's because the whole name `shipping-and-returns` (or its translation) seems to be reserved by the system or maybe by the theme. I don't know the exact cause of this.

So any "common" url won't work, like `shipping-and-returns` or `payment-methods`, notice that if you use the url `shipping-and-returns-dsad-ds-asd` it works perfectly.

Comment: I had the same problem in Magento 2.4 . Found out the problem was caused by Porto Theme which removes the footer in the follwing file:
`app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Porto Theme users in Magento 2.4:
Edit (or better extend in your child theme): `app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

Add the following lines inside `<body></body>`:

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container">
            <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="footer_block" template="html/footer.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="footer.store_switcher" template="switch/stores.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="footer.newsletter" template="subscribe_footer.phtml"/>
            </block>
```

The reason wich causes the problem is that the Porto theme adds its own footer but not for the effected pages from the problem in this topic.